# Modified ROUND UP function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have peculiar requirement where I want to round **up** numbers in below fashion -

```
   1.14 to 1.5
    1.6 to 2
    0.8 to 1
    7.5 to 7.5
```

that is, to nearest multiple of 0.5.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Best Regards

Comment: OK - so you don't need to ROUND to the nearest 0.5, but to ROUND **UP** to the nearest 0.5? That is what MT0 demonstrated.

Comment: This is not "rounding" - you want a ceiling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to round up to the nearest 0.5:

**Test Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
  SELECT 1.14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1.6  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.8  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7.5  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT value,
       CEIL( value * 2 ) / 2 AS rounded_value
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE ROUNDED_VALUE
----- -------------
 1.14           1.5
  1.6             2
  0.8             1
  7.5           7.5
```

If you want to round away from zero to the nearest 0.5 (not the same thing for negative numbers), you can use:

```
SIGN(value) * CEIL(ABS(value)*2) / 2
```

Comment: Perfect!...Thanks a lot for instant solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select floor( val * 2 + 1) / 2
```

Comment: it fails for 7.5 to 7.5

Comment: 7.5 was not in the original scope. But it seems obvious(to me at least) that it should not be rounded to 8